# MSSQL updating set <bulk> where <bulk>

Tags: sql

I'm trying to update a large number of records using an UPDATE, but I just can't seem to figure out how to do this.

```
update Table1
set InternalEndDate = 
    (select OldEndDate
    FROM Table2
    WHERE <a couple of filters>)
where Table1.ReferenceKey in 
    (SELECT Key
    FROM Table2 
    WHERE <a couple of filters>)
```

Both subqueries are the same, except for their output. I understand that this is not the right syntax... but who can help me finding the correect syntax for this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you need a multiple-table update, but I don't the exact syntax for that in MySQL. [The manual page for `UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html) implies you can use a set of normal `JOIN`s like in a `SELECT`, but I'm not confident how this works in practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I ended up just using a CURSOR, which worked fine. I did have to use a temp Table to store my processed data, because all the joining, calculation etc took up a lot of memory and time.